# Unable to compile rabbitmq-c "no rule to make target codegen/amqp-rabbitmq-0.9.1.json"

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm trying to install rabbitmq-c so I can then install the AMQP library from PECL.
Here's my bash history:

```
git clone http://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-codegen/
git clone http://github.com/alanxz/rabbitmq-c
cd rabbitmq-c
autoreconf -i && ./configure && make && make install
```

Error message I get from make is:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `codegen/amqp-rabbitmq-0.9.1.json', needed by `librabbitmq/amqp_framing.h'.  Stop.
```

Anybody know what the issue might be? I have run these commands in the past but obviously the source coming down from git may now be diferent.

Have ensured that erlang, rabbitMQ et al. are installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay,

For anyone else that stumbles upon this the codegen folder has to be a subdirectory of rabbitmq-c. The answer was in the error message :-)